# How to work with result set of meta-functions in Vertica

Tags: subquery, vertica

I want to use result set of meta-function `get_node_dependencies` as a subquery. Is there some way to do it?

Something like this:

```
select v_txtindex.StringTokenizerDelim (dep, chr(10)) over () as words
from (
    select get_node_dependencies() as dep
) t;
```

This query thows an error `Meta-function ("get_node_dependencies") can be used only in the Select clause`.

I know that there is a view `vs_node_dependencies` that returns the same data in more readable way, but the question is generic, not related to any specific meta-function.

Answer (score 1):

Most Vertica meta functions returning a report are for informational purposes on the fly, and can only be used on the outmost part of a query - so you can't apply another function on their output.

But - as you are already prepared to go through development work to split that output into tokens, you might often be even better off by querying `vs_node_dependencies` directly. You'll also be more flexible - is my take on this.